# how to use memory debugging option in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have use android studio .I came across there are  some steps to debug memory leakage in the application.I have attached my screens shot . In that screen shot there is sudden trigger of garbage collector .Can any one guide on this how to use debugging feature in android studio

[image: click to see the screen shot]

Comment: can any body answer on this?